# Is there a way to customize items on the right side of start menu in Windows 7?

Tags: windows, start-menu

OK I know I can right click on it and select properties...

But it only allows me to decide whether an item is shown or hidden.

What I want is, adjust item position on the start menu right side.

More specifically, I want to put the item "games" in the same group where personal folders are. It makes perfectly no sense to put "games" with "computer" and "network" in same group.

Or is there a registry tweak can make this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this you would need to modify the explorer.exe binary. This is generally considered a bad idea because you can seriously mess things up if this goes wrong.

If you're persistent however, you can use a program like Resource Editor to open up the binary and search for the Games string. Once you're there, you can see in that area the other links and you'll be able to essentially copy the code that generates the Games link in that location to put it where the personal folders group is.

Comment: Wow. Seems pretty complicated. Thank you very much, I'll give it a try anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Windows will not let you do that out-of-the-box.  There are, however, many 3rd party applications/tools that let you customize the start menu.
Simply search around on your favorite search engine, you'll find heaps of software.  I can't recommend one specifically, though; some are free, some are unstable, some don't look too good, etc... You'll have to search around and try out some to fit your taste.

Comment: Thank you pleinolijf, but I already did a lot of searching and found nothing does what I wanted.